# Is it recommended that I also apply to jobs I may not be much interested in?

Tags: job-search, canada, first-job

I'm pretty bad at interviews and was wondering what was the "best" first job. I would prefer to stay within Canada.

And through internships and side projects am quite comfortable with front-end, back-end and blockchain (solidity and truffle), but wondering what I should aim for?

Is it better to randomly apply to jobs and see how it goes, or target specific industries that I'm interested in? I know the job market is hot right now and the unemployment is low.

Comment: In a slow market, applying to a job you don't want may be good interview practice, but in a hot market you can get enough interviews to keep in practice going for jobs you want.

Comment: For the Close Voters... this post is no longer asking for a choice, and its clearly answerable. Please reconsider your votes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it better to randomly apply to jobs and see how it goes, or target specific industries that I'm interested in?

**Definitely target specific industries that you are interested in.**

There is few to gain (besides money) by seeking jobs you don't like or are probably not interested in.

That being said, I suggest you try to focus and find your interests first (which you seem to have in some degree), and then reach out for companies that do those kinds of jobs.

First step before interviews is your resume, so remember to *tailor it for each role* so you have better chances of landing an interview or offer. Then you can worry about interviews, moment in which you should try remain calm and professional and answer what you know. Keep it honest, they will know if you are faking it or making things up. It's better to say *"no, I don't know that specific technology, is it similar to X?"* than saying otherwise.